# .htaccess redirect non-www to www problem

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using the following .htaccess file to do few mod-rewrites and also redirect visitors from non-www to www. But the problem is, when someone visit http://domain.com/terms it redirects them to http://www.domain.com/document_terms.php by ignoring the 3rd line.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^terms$ document_terms.php
RewriteRule ^privacy$ document_privacy.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the order of your rules so the www rewriting comes first.

Comment: Got it. I did that earlier but due to cache and since I checked the same URL, it did not appear. Thanks.